# Defining a object by this way - Test object();

Tags: c++

There are some errors,and I can not find them,so I search your help,thanks.
Errors:obj1.print();obj2.print();

Tips:expressions must contain class types.

Changing code and get following output:
TestClass1:0
TestClass2

Attention:

1. Do not alter the main function.
2. Do not add or delete rows.
3. Do not modify the structure of program.

`

```
struct TestClass1 {
    TestClass1(int i=0) {
        m_i = i;
    }
    void print() {
        cout << "TestClass1:" << m_i << endl;
    }
    int m_i;
};
class TestClass2 {
public:
    TestClass2(int) {}
    void print() {
        cout << "TestClass2" << endl;
    }
private:
    ~TestClass2() { }
};
int main() {
    TestClass1 obj1();
    TestClass2 obj2();
    obj1.print();
    obj2.print();
    return 0;
}
```

`

Comment: There are some errors... what are the errors?

Comment: Vexing parse for `TestClass1 obj1();`, -> function declaration

Comment: This will never work without changing the contents of the main function (see: most vexing parse).

Comment: @Rene: You forget power of (:evil:) MACRO.

Comment: @Blaze Errors: obj1.print();obj2.print(); Tips:expressions must contain class types

Answer (score 0):

Without changing the structure of the program I can only point out the problems.

1. `TestClass2` does not have a default constructor to initialize in `TestClass2 obj2();`
2. `TestClass2` destructor is private: "error: temporary of type 'TestClass2' has private destructor"
3. You don't indicate what standard you are compiling to, C++17 the preferred method of initializing objects is using braces eg: `TestClass1 obj1{};` or nothing: `TestClass1 obj1;`: "warning: empty parentheses interpreted as a function declaration [-Wvexing-parse]"
4. Constructors taking a single argument should be declared `explicit` to prevent unwanted conversion, unless that is what you want.

With those changes I get the following output when run:

```
TestClass1:0
TestClass2
```

Comment: Thank you for your assistance,I changed constructor of TestClass2  to  a default constructor and have made private destructor  to public,but it is forbided to change TestClass1 obj1() to any ohter types,so I also can not run the code successful.

Comment: If you are forbidden to change the initialization idiom, then what standard are you required to compile with?

Comment: Any standard can